# Scroll a div on hover using mousewheel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I want is to scroll only the div on which the cursor hovers using the mousewheel (without using the scrollbar).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jquery-scrollLock](http://mohammadyounes.github.io/jquery-scrollLock/), it locks mouse wheel scroll inside container preventing it from propagating to parent element.

HTML:

```
<div data-scrollLock>
 content... 
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('[data-scrollLock]').scrollLock();
```

[Demo](http://mohammadyounes.github.io/jquery-scrollLock/#demo)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `overflow` CSS property.

```css
.scroll {
 height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<p>Some content</p>
<div class="scroll">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec elit accumsan est aliquet aliquam. In eu finibus sapien, eget luctus lacus. Mauris consequat, lorem sodales dictum placerat, velit lectus gravida ligula, in euismod nisl purus non ante. Etiam pretium neque eros, sodales volutpat erat tempus eu. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean ac turpis eu est eleifend malesuada. Pellentesque mauris purus, varius ut laoreet at, ultricies id turpis. Quisque sollicitudin quis tellus a eleifend. In eget euismod urna, vestibulum porttitor velit. Duis auctor, erat a tempor elementum, quam lorem pulvinar nulla, sit amet lobortis magna diam a ex. Nam cursus varius pellentesque. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque quis ligula id leo imperdiet finibus a eget risus. Ut sagittis luctus libero. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas quis elementum nibh.
</div>
<p>Some content</p>
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point that your question is badly written, e.g: "it scrolls with the mouse-wheel"; this implies that your mouse-wheel starts moving or it is related to having the mouse-wheel and it is not, or another example: "when you hover on the left sidebar, it scrolls with the mouse-wheel ", who scrolls what? what is `it`?

I had to login to a gmail inbox to see what are you talking about and what you described is totally different than what I saw, anyway, could be nice if you added a gif too but anyway, what you want to explore is CSS(overflow and position fixed attributes in specific), it is not really a javascript related. Should be addressed that there is no scrolling on hover event, at least not that I noticed, I saw on click. I will add a simple javascript to get you started,

```
var elementToScrollTo = document.getElementById("elementToScrollTo");
// you could also use jQuery, var elementToScrollTo = $("#elementToScrollTo")[0]; 

elementToScrollTo.scrollTop = elementToScrollTo.scrollHeight; // scrolls to the end of the div
```

This main point of this code is to show you the functionality of scrollTop attribute, by finding the distance between the upper bound of the div to the element you'd to scroll down to you could easily do that - and even animating it with an interval.

Please note that there are plenty of questions-alike here, you should learn how to explain yourself.
I hope I helped.

Comment: Sorry for my bad language, I have updated the question.

Comment: Just read up on the CSS attributes I have mentioned and then play around with the javascript I wrote, good luck anyway.

Comment: If I somewhat helped you feel free to +1